# What is the difference between withTransaction and withSession in grails?

Tags: hibernate, session, grails, transactions, grails-orm

I know one gets the underlying session and the other a reference to the current transaction status; however, what are the differences between them and what would be an example use-case for each?

My requirement is to batch save some records within a Service method block.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`withTransaction` is a bit hackish because it allows you to do transactional work anywhere, but it's best to separate your concerns and do the work in a transactional service. A service is transactional by default unless you add `static transactional = false` and can be fine-tuned at the class and/or method level with the `@Transactional` annotation. You should be fine just putting your code in a service method without using `withTransaction` or `withSession`.

`withSession` is a convenient way to access the current Hibernate `Session` (typically the one registered by the OpenSessionInView interceptor). If you want to clear the session, or do other work that's not exposed by GORM, this is a way to access it without accessing the `sessionFactory` or the thread-local holders that Spring uses.

One somewhat valid use of `withTransaction` outside of a transactional service method is to bind a Hibernate `Session` when you're outside of a controller request (i.e. when there's no auto-created `Session`). `withTransaction` will start a transaction and create a `Session` if needed, and keep it open for the duration of the closure. So you can use it to avoid lazy-loading exceptions. We need another way to do this without the overhead of a transaction, for those cases when you're just reading from the database and don't need transactional writes. But for now, this approach works. However if you do database writes, move the code to a service method.

Comment: Thanks Burt.  I was batching records and found that I needed the `withSession` shortcut, as calling `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().clear()` was getting tedious.

Comment: This answer is not strictly true. There are many cases where you want to rollback in a service without throwing an exception to the caller. In this case, the only option is to use withTransaction.

Comment: You almost never want to roll back a transaction with an exception, unless you're genuinely in an exceptional state. The typical antipattern of using an unchecked exception to rollback a transaction takes advantage of a side effect and is inefficient because of the cost of the exception, and more so when using Groovy. But `withTransaction` is _not_ the only proper way to do this. Just use `TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly()
`

Comment: Burt you're the man! I was looking for a way to get the TransactionStatus without using withTransaction. Thanks!

Comment: Actually I tried this on grails 2.5.1, and it failed with the exception No transaction aspect-managed TransactionStatus in scope. However there is another solution, inside the @Transactional annotated method, I saw that there is a magically injected variable, transactionStatus during runtime. You can use this.

Answer (score 3):

[Session](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html) and [TransactionStatus](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/TransactionStatus.html)  are two completely different things. The Session is an abstraction that gives you access to all the hibernate functionality while the TransactionStatus can be used to control the current transaction.

`withSession` can be used if you need direct access to hibernate functions. This can be useful if you want to use a hibernate feature that is not supported directly by Grails/GORM.