# Grails groovy too many hibernate connections

Tags: java, hibernate, batch-file, grails, groovy

I am struggling with manual the transaction management. Background: I need to run quarz crons which run batch processes. It is recommended for batch processing to manually decide when to flush to the db to not slow down the application to much.

I have a pooled hibernate connection as the following

```
dataSource {
        pooled = true
        driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"
        properties {
            maxActive = 50
            maxIdle = 25
            minIdle = 1
            initialSize = 1
            minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
            timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 60000
            numTestsPerEvictionRun = 3
            maxWait = 10000
            testOnBorrow = true
            testWhileIdle = true
            testOnReturn = false
            validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
            validationQueryTimeout = 3
            validationInterval = 15000
            jmxEnabled = true
            maxAge = 10 * 60000
            // http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#JDBC_interceptors
            jdbcInterceptors = "ConnectionState;StatementCache(max=200)"
        }
    }

    hibernate {
        cache.use_second_level_cache = false
        cache.use_query_cache = false
        cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
        show_sql = false
        logSql = false
    }
```

the cron job calls a service in the service i run do the following:

```
    for(int g=0; g<checkResults.size() ;g++) {
        def tmpSearchTerm = SearchTerm.findById((int)results[g+i][0])
        tmpSearchTerm.count=((String)checkResults[g]).toInteger()
        batch.add(tmpSearchTerm)
    }


        //increase counter
        i+=requestSizeTMP
        if (i%(requestSize*4)==0 || i+1==results.size()){
            println "PREPARATION TO WRITE:" + i
            SearchTerm.withSession{
                def tx = session.beginTransaction()
                for (SearchTerm s: batch) {
                    s.save()
                }
                batch.clear()
                tx.commit()
                println ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>writing: ${i}<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<"
            }
            session.flush()
            session.clear()
        }
    }
```

So I am adding things to a batch until I have enough (4x the request size or the last item) and then I am trying to write it to the db.

Everything works fine.. but somehow the code seems to open hibernate transactions and does not close them. I don't really understand why but I am getting a hard error and tomcat crashes with too many connections. I have 2 Problems with that, which i do not understand:

1) If the dataSource is pooled and the maxActive is 50 how can i get a too many connection errors if the limit of tomcat is 500.

2) How do I explicitly terminate the transaction so that i do not have so many open connections?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `withTransaction` because it will manage transaction.

For example

```
Account.withTransaction { status ->
    def source = Account.get(params.from)
    def dest = Account.get(params.to)

    int amount = params.amount.toInteger()
    if (source.active) {
        source.balance -= amount

        if (dest.active) {
            dest.amount += amount
        }
        else {
            status.setRollbackOnly()
        }
    }
}
```

You can look about withTransaction in http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/withTransaction.html

You can see the difference between withSession and withTransaction in https://stackoverflow.com/a/19692615/1610918

------UPDATE-----------

But I would prefer you to use service and it can be called from job.

Comment: if i use withTransaction{ how can i do the commit then because i get the transaction with Transaction tx = Session.beginTransaction() and using withTransactions its not clear to me how i can to the tx.commit and the session.flush

Comment: withTransaction will commit it there is no runtime exception within the block.

Comment: I would prefer you to use service as it can be called from job.